# MongoDB Query to match both single entry and array elements

Tags: java, json, mongodb, query-builder

I have a problem with MongoDB QueryBuilder.

Assume I have a number of documents, that can contain one or more users:

```
{
  "_id": "document1",
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "credentials": {
        "name": "John",
        "lastname": "Watson",
        "middle": "Hemish"
      }
    }
  }
}


{
  "_id": "document2",
  "data": {
    "user": [
      {
        "credentials": {
          "name": "John",
          "lastname": "Nicholson",
          "middle": "Joseph"
        }
      },
      {
        "credentials": {
          "name": "Mary",
          "lastname": "Watson",
          "middle": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}


{
  "_id": "document3",
  "data": {
    "user": [
      {
        "credentials": {
          "name": "John",
          "lastname": "Watson",
          "middle": "Hemish"
        }
      },
      {
        "credentials": {
          "name": "John",
          "lastname": "Nicholson",
          "middle": "Joseph"
        }
      },
      {
        "credentials": {
          "name": "Mary",
          "lastname": "Watson",
          "middle": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is the query, that will return only those documents containing  John Watson as a user.

Here what I got so far:

**1.**

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilder.start("credentials.lastname").is("Watson").and("credentials.name").is("John");
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("data.user").elemMatch(qb.get()).get();
```

this query will return only document3: there is no array in document1 and no match in document2 (but I would like it to return document1 and document3)

**2.**

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("data.user.credentials.lastname").is("Watson").and("data.user.credentials.name").is("John").get();
```

this one will return all three documents: document1 and document3 are desired match, but the query will match as well document2, for it has Watson and John in query fields in the array, no matter that they are separate entries.

Is there any way to make a right query that will return document1 and document3 for John Watson?

I am trying to do it in Java, but any other example would be fine.

Right now I use a workaround combining results from both queries: first I get limit(100) results from the query with elementMatch(), then, if there are less than 100 results, I do the second query and filter all wrong matches. But I hope there is a better and more effective way to get those results.

Comment: Could you convert aggregate query to your query builder form?

Comment: at least I can try this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I could give you at best like the following where `user` would be in an array as unwind value of the key `data`. I think a little bit more effort would lead you to the exact format as you want.

I am sharing it as I think it should serve the purpose or anyhow it should help you.

**The aggregation query**:

```
db.tuttut.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$data.user"},
    { $project: { 
        _id:1, 
        data:1, 
        temp: {name:"$data.user.credentials.name",
               lastname:"$data.user.credentials.lastname"}  
        } }  ,
    { $group:{ 
        _id:"$_id" , 
        data: {$addToSet: "$data"} , 
        temp:{ $addToSet: "$temp"  } }  }, 
    { $match:{ temp:{name:"John",lastname:"Watson"}  }  }  ,
    {$project:{_id:1, data:1}}
]).pretty()
```

**Returned Result:**

```
{
        "_id" : "document1",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "user" : {
                                "credentials" : {
                                        "name" : "John",
                                        "lastname" : "Watson",
                                        "middle" : "Hemish"
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "document3",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "user" : {
                                "credentials" : {
                                        "name" : "John",
                                        "lastname" : "Watson",
                                        "middle" : "Hemish"
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "user" : {
                                "credentials" : {
                                        "name" : "Mary",
                                        "lastname" : "Watson",
                                        "middle" : ""
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "user" : {
                                "credentials" : {
                                        "name" : "John",
                                        "lastname" : "Nicholson",
                                        "middle" : "Joseph"
                                }
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try!

Comment: @yggdraa Thank you too and sorry as I could not give you the exact format.

Comment: well, I tried it, and got 'Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.''
And with allowDiskUse:true it takes too long (database size is ~300Gb, those name fields are indexed, but may be I need to index some more fields?)
(I did add $limit:100 at the end of the query)